# Use database data in MVC Master Page

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Suppose i'd like to display title of latest articles.
for particular `Views` , we use controllers to handle that. but for common section of pages like header or footer ,
How to display data(latest articles) from database (within MVC rules) ?
Note: I use `php`

Please check my approach:

app class:

```
<?php
class app{
    public static function appLoader($app){
        include 'apps/'.$app.'/'.$app.'.class.php';
        new $app;
    }
}
```

test.class.php :

```
class test extends app{
    function __CONSTRUCT(){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

`footer.php`:

```
<footer>
<?php echo app::appLoader("test") // returns 'Hello World' ?>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This is w.r.t .Net MVC**

If you are following MVC pattern - then there's a concept of "Partial Views" - which is just like user controls, and it can be placed in the main page.

**Partial view is also an html page which might just div, no html body head etc because it will be rendered inside main html page**

*You might need to verify the syntax for Partial Views with PHP. The concept remains same for MVC.*

There are various ways to display partial views.

One popular way is the one where Partial view is called by its action method - which will ultimately display the result(the partial view).

The Action method will return a "_Footer" Partial view - where you can put your HTML Code of displaying the data from DB(the latest articles).

**The partial view must bind from the list of articles.** which is popularly known as ***Strong Type Binding*** in .Net - which is nothing but mapping the view(HTML page) to a specific class to display the data from that class.

For your reference the below example can be referred(in .Net):

Create a partial view for footer(_Footer) and call it using Action Method(RenderAction - .Net). This action method can fetch the data from database and display in the partial view(_Footer)

The call to the action method be like from the view(html page):

```
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Footer", new { Area = "Common", id}); }
```

And the Controller and action method like:

```
    public class FooterController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            var vm = new FooterViewModel
            {
                Id = id
            };

            return this.PartialView("_Footer", vm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe this approach ?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP. But if you are following MVC pattern, then there's one concept of Partial Views just like user controls, which can be placed in the main page. You can see the syntax available for PHP for calling the partial views. There are various ways to display partial views. I used the one where I called its action method - which will ultimately display the result. The Action method will return a "_Footer" Partial view - where you can put your HTML Code of displaying the data from DB(the latest articles). Yes the partial view must bind from the list of articles.

Comment: Partial view is also a html page which might just div, no html body head etc because it will be rendered inside main html page

Comment: Thanks.Your comment was more useful than your answer.
Please edit your answer and replace your comment.

Comment: Done. Thanks, I appreciate it was helpful for you.